# soapUI tests reports are not visible in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, soapui

I am using `maven-soapui-extension-plugin:test-multi` to run tests splitted in multiple soapUI projects.

I see that a lot of `TEST-*.xml` are generated in `target/surefire-reports` but I don't see them on the jenkins build page like I do with other projects containing regular junit tests. It seems that jenkins does not detect those reports.

My plugin is configured as such:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.4.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-multi</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFiles>
                    <scan>
                        <baseDirectory>${soapui.folder}</baseDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*-soapui-project.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </scan>
                </projectFiles>
                <host>${soapui.endpoint}</host>
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                <useOutputFolderPerProject>false</useOutputFolderPerProject>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Do I need something else in my configuration or in jenkins?

Comment: did you add JUnit in post build actions in the configuration of your project in Jenkins?

Comment: @AnujTeotia no, I created the project in jenkins as a maven project, it seems that when you do that, you can't add (or customize) the junit report post-build action... It could maybe work with a freestyle project.

Comment: It seems maven project in Jenkins only supports TestNG. Try to move to TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a [problem](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9980) with Jenkins which does not publish surefire reports generated outside the surefire-plugin for maven (non-freestyle) projects.